# xslt transform to html use select="format-date(@ДатаРожд, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')" result: [Language: en]19.09.2014

Tags: xslt, saxon

I use Saxon 9.4 in transform xslt 2.0

a have code in xslt: Дата рождения:<xsl:value-of select="format-date(@ДатаРожд, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]')"/>

transform to html: Дата рождения:[Language: en]19.09.2014

from where the text [Language: en] comes from I do not understand!?

Comment: What is your input XML?

Comment: See also https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#lang-cal-place saying "If the fallback representation uses a different language from that requested, the output string must identify the language actually used, for example by prefixing the string with [Language: Y] (where Y is the language actually used) localized in an implementation-dependent way".

Comment: Which Saxon edition is that? What happens if you provide a language argument to `format-date` like `format-date(@ДатаРожд, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]', 'en', (), ())` (where `en` is just an example, use the language you target with that format)?

Comment: ok, construction helped me: select="format-date(@ДатаРожд, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]', 'en',(),())",

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try a more recent Saxon release: 9.4 is very old.

Secondly, what is the locale setting of your machine? I suspect it's a language that isn't supported in (that version of) Saxon, so Saxon is falling back to English, and when it falls back to a different language, the W3C spec requires this prefix to be output. Of course, this is a little ridiculous when you're using a date format that isn't language-dependent.

Comment: the new version of SAXON 10.2 also displays [Language: en]

Comment: construction helped me select="format-date(@ДатаРожд, '[D01].[M01].[Y0001]', 'en',(),())",  THANKS

Comment: I'm interested to know, though, (a) what the Locale setting is, and (b) which Saxon edition you are using. Saxon-PE and higher use ICU for localization and this supports a very wide range of languages; Saxon-HE has a much more limited selection.